# HTML list not showing side-by-side

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an HTML list with each `<li>` tags with the css `display: inline-block;` while the `<ul>` has `display: block; list-style-type: disc; -webkit-column-count: 4;`. I did the css such that it displays all the divs inside the `<li>` tags as a grid layout. What I want is for it to display the cells side by side, then when one row is full, it goes to the next row. Instead, they are displaying one on top of each other, and goes to the next column instead.

Comment: can you put your code in jsfiddle? so we can see it

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS: `li {display:block; float: left}`

Comment: @Siddharth: Not sure how this does not provide an answer? What this would do is display the list items next to each other on one row and when that row is full, move to the next row. This is in line with what was asked in the question.

Comment: I take back my comment. This is a possible answer. But does it solve the problem, I cant answer that. You are right. I delete my comment. Request you to delete yours too (to keep SO clean).